# Calculate difference between two timestamps in SQL in the same table

Tags: sql-server, cursor, timestamp, datediff

I have a table that the columns are:

```
ID   UserId Serial ModifiedDate
---- ------ ----- ----------------
```

I need to calculate de difference between timestamp from each row. For example if i have the table like this:

```
ID   UserId Serial ModifiedDate
---- ------ ----- ----------------
001    1     1111  2015-07-20 10:56:53.0000000
002    1     1111  2015-07-21 18:49:24.0000000
003    1     1111  2015-07-22 08:49:23.0000000
```

I need to make the difference between the timestamp from 001 and 002, then from 002 and 003 and the result need to be like:

```
ID   UserId Serial ModifiedDate                Difference 
---- ------ ----- ----------------             --------
001    1     1111  2015-07-20 10:56:53.0000000 
002    1     1111  2015-07-21 18:49:24.0000000
003    1     1111  2015-07-22 08:49:23.0000000
```

I trying to work with cursors to do this but I couldn’t find the way to have the result of the difference in an new alias column.

This is my query:

```
DECLARE @id bigint, @lastmodif datetime2(7), @id2 bigint, @lastmodif2 datetime2(7),@total int;

DECLARE status_cursor CURSOR FOR 

SELECT [Id], [ModifiedDate], '0' AS Difference 
FROM [Registrations]
  where p.Serial = 1111  
  Order by ModifiedDate

OPEN status_cursor

DECLARE status_cursor2 CURSOR FOR 

SELECT [Id], [ModifiedDate],'0' AS Difference 
FROM [Registrations]
  where p.Serial = 1111  
  Order by ModifiedDate

OPEN status_cursor2

FETCH NEXT FROM status_cursor2

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
FETCH NEXT FROM status_cursor INTO @regid, @lastmodif
FETCH NEXT FROM status_cursor2 INTO @regid2, @lastmodif2
SET @total = 
        (
           DATEDIFF(second,@lastmodif,@lastmodif2)
        )
UPDATE status_cursor SET Result = @total
```

Comment: what version of sql server?

Comment: the version is 2012 11.0.5532.0

Comment: I tried to use LEAD but i have this message: The Parallel Data Warehouse (PDW) features are not enabled

Comment: @juanfandres : Check alternative solution in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

As per your comment, your SQL Server version is 2012. So you can do this by `LEAD()`

You need to Replace `HH` with desired value

```
SELECT ID,
       UserId,
       Serial,
       ModifiedDate,
       DATEDIFF(HH,ModifiedDate,LEAD(ModifiedDate) over(ORDER BY ID)) AS [Difference]
FROM Times
```

Try below query if `LAG()` doesnt work on your DB because of configuration issues.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CAST(ID AS INT)) AS RN
    FROM times
)

SELECT C1.*,DATEDIFF(HH,C1.MODIFIEDDATE,C2.MODIFIEDDATE) AS [DIFFERENCE]
FROM CTE C1 LEFT JOIN CTE C2 ON C1.RN+1 = C2.RN
```

Comment: He did. Because I asked! ;)

Comment: I tried to use LEAD but i have this message: The Parallel Data Warehouse (PDW) features are not enabled.

Comment: database compatability level?

Answer (score 1):

for sql server 2008 and higher

```
with cte as 
(
    select 1 as Id , 1 as UserID, 1111 as Serial, ' 2015-07-20 10:56:53.0000000' as ModifiedDate
    union all 
    select 
    002,    1,     1111 , '2015-07-21 18:49:24.0000000'
    union all
    select 
    003,    1,     1111,  '2015-07-22 08:49:23.0000000'
)
,
cte2 as (
select *, 
        (select min(ModifiedDate) from cte as nextRow where nextRow.Serial = cte.Serial and nextRow.Id > cte.Id)  as NextModifiedDate

    from 
    cte 
)
select id,USERid,Serial,ModifiedDate,DATEDIFF(SECOND,ModifiedDate,isnull(NextModifiedDate,ModifiedDate)) as Difference 
 from cte2
```

Also, you can use this directly with your table

```
    select * 
            -- ,(select min(ModifiedDate) from Registrations as nextRow where nextRow.Serial = Registrations.Serial and nextRow.Id > Registrations.Id)  as NextModifiedDate
            , DATEDIFF(second,Registrations.ModifiedDate, 
                        isnull((select min(ModifiedDate) from Registrations as nextRow where nextRow.Serial = Registrations.Serial and nextRow.Id > Registrations.Id),Registrations.ModifiedDate)
                       ) as Difference 
        from 
        Registrations
```

Comment: also, you can use this  select * 
   -- ,(select min(ModifiedDate) from Registrations as nextRow where nextRow.Serial = Registrations.Serial and nextRow.Id > Registrations.Id)  as NextModifiedDate
   , DATEDIFF(second,Registrations.ModifiedDate, 
      isnull((select min(ModifiedDate) from Registrations as nextRow where nextRow.Serial = Registrations.Serial and nextRow.Id > Registrations.Id),Registrations.ModifiedDate)
        ) as Difference 
  from 
  Registrations

Comment: I tried to use the query directly in the table but when i have a difference between 2 timestamp like this: 2015-07-22 08:49:23.0000000 - 2015-07-22 08:50:08.0000000 i have negative difference and is not representative the number

Comment: i solved the issue with negative difference. Now i have the problem when i have 2 equals timestamps. In the difference column i have te same number. For example: i have this 3 rows 2015-07-26 22:42:03.0000000 / 2015-07-26 22:42:03.0000000 / 2015-07-27 07:07:16.0000000. As you see the first 2 are equals so in the difference column i have the same number for the first 2 that is the difference between the 2nd one and the 3er one.

Answer (score 0):

This works for 2008 and greater returning difference in seconds.

```
 WITH cte AS (SELECT ID, ModifiedDate, 
   DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) AS Ranking from Registrations),

 SELECT cte1.ID, cte1.ModifiedDate, 
   DATEDIFF(ss, cte1.ModifiedDate, cte2.ModifiedDate) AS TimeDiff 
   FROM cte cte1, cte cte2 
   WHERE cte1.Ranking = cte2.Ranking - 1
```